# Android: How to open default numeric keyboard like screen shot?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing such type issues for invoking such type default numeric keyboard.
Please suggest what i can do for the same.

Thanks,
Rakesh

[For more details please see this link (Portrait mode)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/do4ofu9kwrljott/Screenshot_2013-10-22-15-01-05.png)

[For more details please see this link (Landscape mode)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/90diefzv6vqfx2q/Screenshot_2013-10-22-14-56-05.png)

Comment: what is the  problem you are facing ??

Comment: Actually just i want to open numeric keyboard like given screen shot. Any idea you have?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open a numeric keyboard in your `EditText` widget, you can set the `inputType` to `number` . [Ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: Hi Ye Lin Aung,Noted...thanks for your quick reply. My problem is that when I am using input type number then buttons show in grid format in tablet in both direction like landscape or portrait. I want to open just given keyboard which is used in date picker edit text. Please review one time more. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may work.

```
<EditText   
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:inputType="phone" 
></EditText>
```

Comment: Hi Rethinavel,Noted...thanks for your quick reply. My problem is that when I am using input type number then buttons show in grid format in tablet in both direction like landscape or portrait. I want to open just given keyboard which is used in date picker edit text. Please review one time more. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:
input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);